# ScrollView won't scroll even after filling viewPort

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have an issue where my screen won't even scroll and I'm not sure why. I wrapped everything that needs to scroll into a `ScrollView` and have a `LinearLayout` as its single child. I also set `fillViewPorts=true` and filled up the entire space of the layout. I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/comments_coordinator_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/comments_coordinator_layout"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/view_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:background="#e6e6e6">

                <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
                    fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/poster_name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:id="@+id/post_date"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
                    android:layout_below="@id/poster_name"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/view_status" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/container_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/send_message">
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/send_message"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="top|left"
                        android:hint="Comment back!"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="send"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: lodlock is right you should give nested scrollVIew a try

Comment: @GeorgeThomas I just tried it and it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView can be problematic when being used in a CoordinatorLayout. Switching to a [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) might fix your problem.

Comment: Hi, I just tried that but I get an error when I try to do `        setContentView(R.layout.<LayoutName>);`. It says: `Didn't find class "android.view.NestedScrollView" on path`. I also tried doing `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` but that produced the same result as when i first asked the question.